# dplyr filter or [ ] with two inputs

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I'm developing a shiny app and I need to filter a `tibble` by a value. I have 3 different `selectInput()` that allow the user to choose a column (input$col) and two values (input$value1 and input$value2). So for example I have a dataframe with a column `sex = c(M, W, M, M, M, W, M)` input$col will be `sex` and input$value1 will be `M` or `W`.

Now if I use `dplyr::filter()` it doesn't work but if I use `[]` it works. What's wrong with filter? Here it's my code

```
#doesn't work
data() %>% dplyr::filter(input$col %in% input$value1 | input$col %in% input$value2)

#it works
data()[data()[[input$col]] %in% c(input$value1, input$value2),]
```

In the dplyr version I tried also `==` instead of `%in%` but doesnt' change anything. I would like to know if it's my mistake or it is impossible to do with filter()

Comment: This is non-standard evaluation for dplyr, you need to use the bang-bang to quote-unquote. i.e. `data() %>% dplyr::filter(!! input$col %in% input$value1 | !! input$col %in% input$value2)`. See explanation: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/

Comment: @csgroen is completely right, however the preferred way changed a bit, now it is recommended to use `.data[[input$col]]`, see e.g. [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#data-masking)

Comment: Thanks guys! I've never heard about that bang-bang. I tried both solution the first one doesn't work while the @starja solution worked. So my question now is: are there any differences between my solution (with R base) and the `dplyr` solution? I mean in terms of reliability.

Comment: No, both are fine, just choose the coding style you're more comfortable with